# Remove NAs from data frame

Tags: r, analysis

I have my data as follows:

```
Date         Med1    Med2    Med3    Med4
2013-03-01    19      23     NA       33
2013-03-01    25      NA     19       27
2013-03-01    26      23     15       NA
2013-03-01    NA      27     NA       25
```

I would want my data in the following format:

```
Date         Med1    Med2    Med3    Med4
2013-03-01    19      23              33
2013-03-01    25             19       27
2013-03-01    26      23     15        
2013-03-01            27              25
```

i.e, I want to replace the NAs with empty cells.

I tried functions such as `na.omit(df)`, `na.exclude(df)`. In both the cases, the row which has NA is being omitted or excluded. I dont want to drop off the entire row or column but just the NA.

Please note that I dont want the NAs to be replaced by 0s. I want a blank space replacing NA.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You have numeric values there.  If the NA values are replaced with "empty cells", then they will no longer be numeric and it will make calculations more difficult.  If you need to make calculations with this data, I'd suggest you leave it as-is.

Comment: I will not be making any calculations with that. I will plotting the data using data.table.

Comment: Okay, then you can do this easily with `df[is.na(df)] <- ""`

Comment: AH!!! How silly of me!.. I was doing it like this is.na(df) <- "". Thanks Richard!

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much the opposite. :)

Comment: Then do `df[df == 0L] <- ""`

Comment: Thanks! Did that same thing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done as follows:

```
df[is.na(df)] <- ""
```

Thanks Richard!